# Web Scraping using Selenium not returning same results as on the UI

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

Last week User @KunduK  kindly helped me scrap a website to return the address of a [particular record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75400104/scrape-name-address-from-website-site-using-selenium-python)

Record in question : https://register.fca.org.uk/s/firm?id=001b000000MfQU0AAN

By Using the following snippet of Code;

```
address=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h4[data-aura-rendered-by] ~p:nth-of-type(1)"))).text
print(address)
```

However whilst trying to understand the snippet i started to see some additional data being returned.

On the screen shot below, the Left is the expected results to be returned, however on the right is what is being returned.

Inspecting the element i can see there is an additional row (highlighted in yellow)(that's not being presented on the UI (right hand side)

[image: Company Address]

I am also trying to get the "Website" and Reference Number" and following the example provided before, however following these steps (https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/selenium-python/) i am not able to get the desired results being returned

**Current Code:**

```
Website=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".accordion_text h4"))).text
print(Website)
```

**Website Inspect**

[image: website Inspect]

Looking forward to your help!

Answer (score 0):

To extract the *Website address* and *Firm reference number* ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *Website address*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://register.fca.org.uk/s/firm?id=001b000000MfQU0AAN')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h4[text()='Website']//following-sibling::a[1]"))).get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using **Firm reference number**:

  ```
  driver.get('https://register.fca.org.uk/s/firm?id=001b000000MfQU0AAN')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h4[text()='Firm reference number']//following-sibling::p[1]"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  https://www.masonowen.com/
  311960
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902072/7429447)

Comment: To extract the the _Name_ and _Address_ see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75448167/7429447) to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75400104/7429447).